# How to read file string xml file with prefix

Tags: c#, xml

This is mycode. I want to get elements in string xml but i didn't. Please help me.

`$`

```
   string xml = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><s:Body><GetCustomerInfoResponse xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><GetCustomerInfoResult xmlns:a='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PaymentGatewayEVNSPC' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'><a:Address>137 Phường Tân Xuyên</a:Address><a:Bills><a:BillInfo><a:Amount>1516682</a:Amount><a:BillCode>170810TD</a:BillCode><a:DenNgay i:nil='true'></a:DenNgay><a:HoaDonID>33045487</a:HoaDonID><a:Month>8</a:Month><a:SoHo>0</a:SoHo><a:TuNgay i:nil='true'></a:TuNgay><a:TyLeGia i:nil='true'></a:TyLeGia><a:Year>2017</a:Year></a:BillInfo><a:BillInfo><a:Amount>89000</a:Amount><a:BillCode>170810DC</a:BillCode><a:DenNgay i:nil='true'></a:DenNgay><a:HoaDonID>33045487</a:HoaDonID><a:Month>8</a:Month><a:SoHo>0</a:SoHo><a:TuNgay i:nil='true'></a:TuNgay><a:TyLeGia i:nil='true'></a:TyLeGia><a:Year>2017</a:Year></a:BillInfo><a:BillInfo><a:Amount>148028</a:Amount><a:BillCode>170810VC</a:BillCode><a:DenNgay i:nil='true'></a:DenNgay><a:HoaDonID>33045488</a:HoaDonID><a:Month>8</a:Month><a:SoHo>0</a:SoHo><a:TuNgay i:nil='true'></a:TuNgay><a:TyLeGia i:nil='true'></a:TyLeGia><a:Year>2017</a:Year></a:BillInfo></a:Bills><a:CustomerCode>PB14010040801</a:CustomerCode><a:DanhSo>44900L36</a:DanhSo><a:MaSoThue></a:MaSoThue><a:MaTram></a:MaTram><a:Name>Cơ Sở Mộc Thành Tài</a:Name><a:NganhNghe></a:NganhNghe><a:PhienGCS></a:PhienGCS><a:Session></a:Session><a:SoCongTo>14226305</a:SoCongTo><a:SoGhiChiSo>A1010D001</a:SoGhiChiSo></GetCustomerInfoResult></GetCustomerInfoResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
```

`window.jQuery`

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

```
        var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
       // XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        // ns.AddNamespace("xmlns","'http://tempuri.org/'");
        ns.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PaymentGatewayEVNSPC");
        ns.AddNamespace("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");


        string xpath = "s:Envelope/s:Body/GetCustomerInfoResponse/GetCustomerInfoResult";
        // string xpath = "myDataz/listS/sog";
        var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath,ns);
        ;

        foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
        {
            Console.Write(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("a:Address",ns).InnerXml);
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
```

Comment: Remove "s:" and "a:" from xml string.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230605/how-to-parse-xml-with-namespace

Comment: An explicit question may help in clearing up what the problem is.

Comment: This kind of work is easier with XDocument , are you tied to using XmlDocument?

Comment: Sorry i am new member ... this is my code and it not working .i want to get elements in string xml but i didn't .please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, in a namespaced document, you can't use XPath with the default namespace. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271875) for more info.

This works:

```
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
ns.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
ns.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PaymentGatewayEVNSPC");
ns.AddNamespace("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
//Add a prefix for the default namespace for GetCustomerInfoResponse and GeteCustomerInforResult
ns.AddNamespace("t","http://tempuri.org/");

string xpath = "s:Envelope/s:Body/t:GetCustomerInfoResponse/t:GetCustomerInfoResult";
var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath, ns);

foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
{
    Console.Write(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("a:Address", ns).InnerXml);
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```